# use didSelectRowAtIndexPath: methods ， first time did not pass the cell value to another controller,tried twice or more than it worked

Tags: uitableview

Call didSelectRowAtIndexPath: methods to pass cell value to another cell,when first click any line of tableViewCell cell, the data can not be passed to another Controller View, the second or after than  can successfully passed the  value.

- -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  self.updateNoification.nEntity = (NotificationEntity*) [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.updateNoification.nEntity getId]);

self.updateNoification.title = @“modify";

[self.updateNoification updateForReadViewValue];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.updateNoification animated:YES];
}

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I am so sorry that this is my first time ask question format not suitable for the up list

Comment: When first click any line  of  tableViewCell cell, the data can not be passed to another Controller View, the second or after then  can successfully passed the  value.